# django exclude related parameter

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

I'm not sure the title is correct for what I'm asking, but I'll try my best with english:

I have 2 models:

```
class Definition(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
  definition = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
  creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='definition_ex', blank=True, null=True)
```

and

```
class DefinitionGroup(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
  group = models.ForeignKey(Class, related_name = 'definition_group_by_date')
  date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  answers = models.ManyToManyField(Definition, related_name='definition_answers', blank=True, null=True)
```

Ok, what I what to do is:

```
dg = list(DefinitionGroup.objects.filter(group=g).filter(date__lte=datetime.date.today()).exclude(answers.creator=user))
```

But I'm getting an error I don't know how to solve.

Any tips on how I can do that?

Comment: can you please paste traceback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is:

```
.exclude(answers.creator=user))
```

you cant do that, try this:

```
.exclude(answers__creator=user))
```